# Qt 5.15 mingw missing debug dlls *d.dll in folder bin

Tags: debugging, windows-10, mingw-w64, qt5.15

i installed Qt Creator with Qt5.15 by Qt maintenance tool and i`m missing the debug dlls like QtCored.dll in my bin folder of mingw...what can i do?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? Is there anyone out there with a solution?

Comment: I installed an old version. I didn't find a solution till now...

Comment: What problem is it causing? I'm seeing the same thing - I can build and run OK from Qt Creator, but I also need to do scripted builds from the command line, and they seem to need Qt*d.dll. I've asked another question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65439836/2303274

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by doing a clean build. So, what problem is the absence of debug dlls actually causing you?

Comment: The problem is when you include some none-Qt (e.g. c, c++) dlls which needs the debug dlls

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect that Qt no longer add a "d" suffix to their debug .dlls. What happens if you link your project with Qt5Core.dll rather than Qt5Cored.dll?