# Executable image works fine with Qt 5.11.3; won't load with 5.15.0

Tags: qt

We are developing a Windows program using Qt.

I've recently installed Qt 5.15.0 on one of the development machines. On that machine, if I run my tests against Qt 5.11.3, they run fine. However, if I try to run against 5.15.0, they will not run. All the tests I have tried display this error dialog:

[image: Screenshot of test_tvstringlist.exe error dialog]

and a similar dialog about `Qt5Testd.dll`.

Running against 5.11.3, I have, amongst other directories, `C:\Qt\5.11.3\mingw53_32\bin` in my path. This directory contains, amongst other files, `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Cored.dll`, `Qt5Test.dll` and `Qt5Testd.dll`.

Running against 5.15.0, `C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_32\bin` lies on my path. That directory includes `Qt5Core.dll` and `Qt5Test.dll`, but neither `Qt5Cored.dll` nor `Qt5Testd.dll`.

[I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65205045/2303274) which I suspect relates to the same issue. In view of the rephrasing and additional detail, I hope you will forgive the duplication.]

### Update

Both the 5.11.3 and the 5.15.0 images were built by adding the appropriate directories to PATH (either `C:\Qt\5.11.3\mingw53_32\bin` and `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32` or `...\5.15.0\mingw81_32\...` and `...\mingw810_32\...`) and then executing

```
qmake <project.pro> -r CONFIG+=debug
mingw32-make
```

What do I need to do differently to be able to run the tests?

Comment: Why the close vote, please?

Comment: There is no question asked.

Comment: Fair point :-). I shall edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think binaries built with MinGW 8 are binary compatible with binaries built with MinGW 5. Your application and Qt libraries must be built with same compiler.

Comment: I'm running different binaries, built with the appropriate compiler in each case - running against 5.11.3 I've compiled with the gcc in C:\Qt\5.11.3\mingw530_32 and I used the compiler in ...mingw810_32 to run against 5.15.0.

Comment: :blush: It turns out that this was almost certainly the cause of my problem. Running interactively from Qt Creator, the build directory (by default) has the release built into its name, so after switching releases, you will automatically do a clean build, even if you don't have a release-specific build directory, it's likely that you would automatically try a clean build if faced by this kind of problem. On the development machine in question, with scripted builds, the build directory was shared between releases. A manual `rm -rf build` fixed the problem.